# How to set minimum term frequency in query match?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to setup a query that filter out returned results with the term mentioned 2 times in a field?

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex {2,}.

Note it s depend of your analyzer.

Comment: can you elaborate please? Thanks

Comment: so you use a regex to catch four field, and you ask regex to contains it twice, cant test on my smartphone right now, but should be something like that:  "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "postcode": "*keyword*{2,}" 
        }
    }

Comment: Thanks. it sounds to me that my question was not clear. I just updated it. what I want is to filter out the returned results with the term mentioned 2 times, not to query result for term mention at least 2 times.